# How to set a MSSQLServer Stored Procedure Input Parameter to an Output parameter for passback.

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

So I have a stored proc and I am trying to set an output parameter to an input parameter but I can't get it to work.

Essentially here is my proc...

```
...
@InID DECIMAL(9),
@ID DECIMAL(9) OUTPUT,
...
if @InID is not null
begin
   @ID = @InID
end
...
```

But this shows as having a syntax error. How do I fix this?

Comment: Change @ID=@InID to SET @ID=@InID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create  procedure [dbo].[StackOverflow]
(
    @InID DECIMAL(9),
    @ID DECIMAL(9) OUTPUT
)
as
begin

if @InID is not null
begin
   set @ID = @InID
end
end
```

What is the syntax error you got? The next works fine:

```
declare @out as decimal
exec StackOverflow 1, @out
```